# Can anybody parse this sentence for me, please?

Tags: grammaticality

"Quarles is viewed by many policy analysts as a business-friendly pick who benefits from having experience in the federal government and **his business ties are unlikely to be viewed by senior senators his Wall Street ties as a handicap.**"

Source: http://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-banks-regulation-quarles-idUSKBN19X2ZT?il=0

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an editing error: the author wrote a first version "senior senators are unlikely to view his Wall Street ties as a handicap", then rewrote this as "his business ties are unlikely to be viewed by senior senators as a handicap", but forgot to delete "his Wall Street ties".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an editing error by Reuters.

If I had to guess, the original sentence was:

> Quarles is viewed by many policy analysts as a business-friendly pick
>   who benefits from having experience in the federal government and
>   senior senators are unlikely to view his Wall Street ties as a
>   handicap.

That's a sentence that can be parsed, but contains a parallel structure error because the first clause is passive voice and the second is not. The editor also seems have decided to replace "Wall Street ties" with "business ties." In the effort to make both changes, a phrase was left duplicated. I imagine the intended correction should look more like:

> Quarles is viewed by many policy analysts as a business-friendly pick
>   who benefits from having experience in the federal government and his
>   business ties are unlikely to be viewed by senior senators as a
>   handicap.